# SharePoint Online Workflow Convert word doc to PDF

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, document-converter, microsoft-flow

**Office 365/ SharePoint Online E3 tenant.**

I have requirement to convert a word document in a document library to PDF once a document is approved via an approval workflow process. Is it possible to achieve this using the SharePoint Designer Workflow or Using the new Microsoft Flow?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you but using third party solutions:

http://blog.muhimbi.com/2012/02/convert-document-types-using-pdf.html

Comment: thanks. But i'm looking for out of the box functionality

Comment: https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/converting-a-librarys-word-documents-to-pdf-using-word-automation-services-for-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: check the above link https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/converting-a-librarys-word-documents-to-pdf-using-word-automation-services-for-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: thanks for sharing this link... but it's a code based approach. I'm looking for something that can be achieved using Designer workflow

Comment: There is no out of the box facility. The Link Sam provided is good, but the better one (Same product, but for SP Online) is http://www.muhimbi-online.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Plumsail Documents](https://plumsail.com/documents/) to convert DOCX to PDF. Please review [this article](https://plumsail.com/docs/documents/v1.x/flow/how-tos/documents/convert-word-to-pdf.html) with the example of Flow.

This is a screenshot of the Flow:
[image]

You also can create PDF from templates:

- [Create PDF from DOCX template](https://plumsail.com/docs/documents/v1.x/flow/how-tos/documents/create-pdf-from-docx-template.html)
- [Create PDF from HTML template](https://plumsail.com/docs/documents/v1.x/flow/how-tos/documents/create-pdf-from-html-template.html)

Note: Plumsail Actions is a paid solution and I'm a member of the development team.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use the Graph api to get files in another format:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content-format?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http